# How to close a custom dialog automatically

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to open a dialog. And dismiss automatically after a few seconds, the button in the dialog should also dismiss a dialog, whatever happens first. But I can't find the right way to close the dialog after time is up

I use the next custom dialog

```
private void okShowDialog(String title, String message){
    vibrate();
    final Dialog dialogo=new Dialog(Login.this);
    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.okdialog);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    TextView errorTitle=dialogo.findViewById(R.id.lblTitleDialog);
    errorTitle.setText(title);
    TextView errorMessage=dialogo.findViewById(R.id.txtErrorDialog);
    errorMessage.setText(message);
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btnCont);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    dialogo.show();
}
```

The dialog XML is very simple, it just shows a title, message, and button.

I've been through this for a couple of days and can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to add Handler:

```
dialogo.show();

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Close dialog after 1000ms
        dialogo.cancel();
    }
}, 1000);
```

After 1000 ms (1 sec) Your dialog will be closed. I think that You don't have to check if a dialog was closed with a button and when You call again `close` on closed dialog You won't get any error but if I am not right just add a boolean variable to control if a dialog was closed by a button.

Comment: Just found out I forgot to thank you, thanks a lot!!... It was just what I needed

Answer (score 4):

You could also use Kotlin Coroutine:

```
'build your dialog...'
dialog.setOnShowListener {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        delay(length)
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
dialog.show()
```

Where 'length' is the time in milliseconds that you want the dialog to show for.